# Populate a property in load options from a child object

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I'm using Linq to sql to populate my object. Previously, I was using deferred loading and then iterating through my list accessing the child objects to force loading. This isn't a very good solution with the large data set I have so I am now setting the LoadOptions in my data context to grab it all initially.

The one problem I've run into is that before I was manually loading a single property on each iteration through my list and I'm not sure how to accomplish this now. It's just a simple string value.

```
 info.CreatedByName = info.CreatedBy.Name;
```

In my data context, I'm specifying my load options as such:

```
 DataLoadOptions loadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
 loadOptions.LoadWith<Info>(info => info.Owner);
 loadOptions.LoadWith<Info>(info => info.CreatedBy);
```

Is there a way to specify assignment of this property in my load options? Something like:

```
 loadOptions.LoadWith<Info>(info => info.CreatedByName)
```

Comment: Where is CreatedByName defined?

Comment: CreatedByName is defined in the Info partial class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can use LoadOptions in this way. You could use a projection container class, if you don't need to perform object tracking, and explicitally set the property upon construction.

```
from info in context.Infos
select new InfoContainer
{
    CreatedByName = CreatedBy.Name
}
```

You could add a partial class for Info and add a property that refers to CreatedBy.Name

```
public string CreatedByName
{
    get
    {
        return CreatedBy.Name;
    }
}
```

That would assume that the CreatedBy is loaded, or lazy load it if its not populated.

Comment: I was using automatic properties here so I set CreatedByName = CreatedBy.Name in an OnLoaded() event.

Answer (score 1):

Everything you do is perfectly valid, yet you must explicitly select CreatedBy in your query after setting context's LoadWith options, eg

```
var result = from info in context.Infos
             join user in context.Users on info.CreatedById equals user.Id
             select info;
```

I've had the same problem, check [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425535/how-to-select-all-parent-objects-into-datacontext-using-single-linq-query/2498384#2498384)